# Why are moves more expensive than passing by const&?

Tags: c++, assembly, move, copy-constructor, lifetime

I'm passing a few objects into a constructor right before their lifetime ends.

```
int main(){

    //I wanted to avoid short string optimization in this example.
    const std::string a(25,"a");
    const std::string b(25,"b");
    const std::string c(25,"c");

    Foo f{a,b,c};
}
```

There are two options I considered for Foo's constructor.

`const&` (calling string's copy constructor):

```
Foo(const std::string & a,
    const std::string & b,
    const std::string & c)
:a(a)
,b(b)
,c(c)
{}
```

`std::move` (calling string's move constructor):

```
Foo(std::string a,
    std::string b,
    std::string c)
:a(std::move(a))
,b(std::move(b))
,c(std::move(c))
{}
```

With `-01` on `gcc 7`, I got the following results:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
| constructor | assembly instructions |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| const&      |                   192 |
| move        |                   264 |
+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Why is `const&` less instructions?
I thought a move would be cheaper than creating a new string via the copy constructor.

What is the rule of thumb for passing variables as constructor arguments
when the lifetime of those arguments is ending?

Comment: remove `const` from `a,b,c` in `main` and the parameters; and use `move` in the function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling the move constructor. Your argument strings are const. So when you use `std::move` on them, the result is `const std::string&&`. That doesn't invoke the move constructor, who's signature takes `std::string&&`.

Comment: My mistake.  I *was* calling without const.  The same results from passing by value and using move.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler doesn't make a special version of the constructor for main to call, then `main` is still calling a function with the signature  `Foo(std::string a,  std::string b,    std::string c);`

Unless it inlines, or gcc makes a clone of it that actually passes args differently, the code in the *definition* of a function can't change how it's called.

Imagine the constructor definition was in a separate file, and wasn't even visible while `main` was being compiled, only the prototype.  This is similar to what you get by compiling with only `-O1`.